# When is ROBOCOPY done?

Tags: cmd, robocopy

I am using ROBOCOPY to copy 125 files, some small, many in the MiB range, up to 65 GiB.

```
ROBOCOPY D:\the\dir\prod F:\the\dir\devl *.txt /MT:64
```

After one (1) hour, it appears that all 125 files are in the target directory. However, the cmd line output is still on the 15th file. Is it done? Why is the cmd output still waiting?

Comment: Did you solve it, please ?

Comment: ROBOCOPY is not done until it returns. The destination file names are present and size is allocated in the directory listing. That does not mean that all of the allocated size has been copied.

Answer (score 0):

Either because

[1] the 65GB file takes for ever in your mind, but the PC is still copying it. I would wait.

or

[2] Something has interrupted the copying midway. Try with /R:5 for retries if it failed or if something has touched your source file interrupting the copy.

Also I would run it with a /LOG:file and /TEE of some sort to see what it's doing.

Try and refresh the destination folder too whilst it's copying and see if the filesize is changing.